# Android socket still can write without exception when wifi has been disconnected

Tags: android, sockets, wifi

I write an Android socket demo which just post user's input to server.
I establish a socket from android client through wifi connection, and everything goes well, the server can receive the message send from android client. The problem is, then I close WIFI of phone, but the socket can write without exception.

The code of Android client:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private SocketHandlerThread thread;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        thread = new SocketHandlerThread("ScoketTest");
        thread.start();
    }

    class SocketHandlerThread extends HandlerThread {
        private Socket socket;
        private Handler handler;

        public SocketHandlerThread(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        public SocketHandlerThread(String name, int priority) {
            super(name, priority);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket = new Socket("192.168.60.184", 1990);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("SocketTest", e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }
            super.run();
        }

        Handler getHandler() {
            if (handler == null) {
                handler = new Handler(getLooper());
            }
            return handler;
        }

        void send(final String text) {
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("SocketTest", "Start send text: " + text);
                    try {
                        socket.getOutputStream().write((text + "\n").getBytes());
                        socket.getOutputStream().flush();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("SocketTest", e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                    }
                    Log.e("SocketTest", "Text has been send:" + text);
                }
            };
            getHandler().post(runnable);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onLooperPrepared() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    findViewById(R.id.button).setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void send(View view) {
        String text = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.text)).getText().toString();
        thread.send(text);
    }
}
```

The code of Server:

```
public class SocketTestServer {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;

    SocketTestServer() throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1990);
    }

    void start() throws IOException {
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        clientSocket.getInputStream();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
        BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(inputLine);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SocketTestServer server = new SocketTestServer();
        server.start();
    }
}
```

I try on several phones. On Galaxy Nexus(4.2.1) an exception was thrown as expected, but on some MOTO or HTC phones socket can still write without any exception, which means I may loss some messages that I thought has been received successfully.
How could I get known that the socket connection was broken on any type of phone?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

p.s
I know the Connective Change Broadcast, but before receive the broadcast the client may have write some message through the broken socket.

Though adding receive check on application protocol can solve the message lossing problem, I prefer to guarantee reliability on transport layer which the TCP protocol promise to do.

Answer (score 0):

I use Writer & IOException in my socket, it works fine. Try this:

```
public static void sendUTF(String str)
    {
        try
        {
            outWriter.write(str + '\n');
            outWriter.flush();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            outServ.setText("Connection lost!");
        }
    }

public static Writer outWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the TCP stack (OS level) and is a problem difficult to solve.
It happens also if the server is the one which lose connection (try to restart your server after opening the socket and no client will notice)... you will suffer a "broken pipe error" next time you send a packet through the socket.

So, there are two scenarios:

1- broken pipe when client sends information.

In this scenario you should capture the IOException and retry to open the connection (you will have to define your retry policies).

2- broken pipe when the server lose connectivity

When the server lose connection the client doesn't notice so, In this scenario you should send packets to the server in a regular basis (polling technique) and try to reconnect just in case the connection is lost.
This is needed just if you receive from the server updates, if you traffic is always client-->server only the scenario 1 applies.